# Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode) blutooth dongle doesn't work in Lubuntu with 5.13.0-40-generic kernel

Tags: kernel, bluetooth

Not only in this Linux version I tested with different Linux distro(s) the Bluetooth dongle from **Cambridge Silicon Radio** doesn't seem to work at all. I have seen some posts saying it was a problem up to kernel version below 5.6 but it doesn't work even in greater version.

But the strange thing is that when I run `sudo rfkill list` command it shows :

```
3: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

That means the dongle is detected.

I also ran `sudo hciconfig -a` it shows up the bluetooth address.

But running `hcitool dev` says :

```
Devices :
```

Means no device. I cannot also use `hcitool scan` or anything. Where I am going wrong? I am a very newcomer to Linux os.

Comment: Search on `Cambridge Silicon Radio Bluetooth Dongle linux`. There are a number of possibilities, one of which is you need the firmware code. `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` may show similar to `Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd not found`